# Changing the index of array and then returning back to the previous one

Tags: java

I would like to know if there is a possibility to check the condition with the index 1 of the array and then if the condition does not match move to another index but return back to the first index once again.

like if I have an array named numbers, I would like to check if the numbers[0] satisfies the condition if yes proceed else check numbers[1] and so on. But once numbers[1] gets checked return back to numbers[0] and check if now the condition match else move to numbers[2].

```
if (numbers[x] % row == 0 || numbers[x] % column == 0) {
  output[x] = 1;
  if (numbers[x] % row == 0) {
    column = -(numbers[x] / row);
  } else {
    row = -(numbers[x] / column);
  }
} else {
  output[x] = 0;
}
```

Full Program.
    package acm;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


/**
*
* @author amosh
*/
public class ACM {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int row;
    int column;
    int value=0;
    int value1;
    int value2=0;
    int friendsNumber;
    char letter;
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
    do{ 
        System.out.println("Enter The number of friends"+
                " between whom you want to divide"+" the choclate: ");
        friendsNumber=keyboard.nextInt();
        if(friendsNumber==0){
            System.out.println("The Program exited as you entered"+
                    " 0 number of friends to divide the chocolate.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Type in the dimension of the choclate");
        System.out.println("Enter the number of row:");
        row= keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of column:");
        column=keyboard.nextInt();
        if(row==0 || column==0){
            System.out.println("Illegal number of row or column."+
                    " Program Exited");
            System.exit(0);

        }
        value= dimension(row, column, value);
        keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.print("How much Pieces Do Each Friend Need? \n"+
            "Enter the elements seperated by spaces: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer divisionInput= new StringTokenizer(input);
        int count = divisionInput.countTokens();
        int[] numbers= new int[count];
        int[] output= new int[count];

        for(int x=0; x<count;x++){
        numbers[x] = Integer.parseInt((String)divisionInput.nextElement());
        if(numbers[x]==0){
        System.out.println("You entered a number that could not be"+
                "divided. So, the program exited.");
        System.exit(0);
        }
        if(numbers[x]%row==0 || numbers[x]%column==0)
         {
          output[x]=1;
          if(numbers[x]%row==0)
          {
              column=-(numbers[x]/row);
          }
          else{
              row=-(numbers[x]/column);
          }
         }
        else{
            output[x]=0;
        }
     }   
         boolean printed=false;
         for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
             if(output[i]==0){
                 if(!printed){
                 System.out.println("NO");
                 printed=true;}

             }
             else{
                 if(!printed){
                     System.out.println("YES");
                     printed=true;
                 }
             }

         }
        System.out.println("Do you want to divide another choclate "+"(Y/N)?");
        String pointer=keyboard.next();
        letter=pointer.charAt(0);
    }while(letter=='y' || letter=='Y' );
    }
public static int dimension(int row, int column, int result){
result= row * column;
return result;
}




public static char lastOutput(){
char letter;
Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Do you want to divide another choclate "+"(Y/N)?");
        String pointer=keyboard.next();
        letter=pointer.charAt(0);
        return letter;
 }
 }
```

Comment: are you saying your original array will be modified while you are iterating through it?? i think you will be getting a ConcurrentModifcationException...

Comment: it should be possible. .Can you post what have you done so far..

Comment: add it to the question with proper formatting..

Comment: what is the expected output if numbers[]={1,2,3,4,5,6}

Comment: @Jobin overhere when the numbers[0] does not satisfy the relation it immediately writes 0 in the array output[x]. But, what I want is that, if numbers[0] does not satisfy the relation move to numbers[1] check the condition if it satisfies write 1 in the array output[x] else move to numberss[2]. Suppose numbers[2] satisfies the condition and writes 1 in output[1], I would like to check again with the numbers[0], and numbers[1] if they satisfy write 1 in output[x] else move to numbers[3] and so on.

Comment: okay you need a loop here. . by the way what is row and column? would be good if you post the whole compilable code

Comment: @Jobin now at first check with the element 1. It the element is not the multiple of the number of row or column, i would like the program to at first check the condition with element 2 and then after the change takes place i would like to check the condition again with 1.

Comment: @Jobin row and column is just the dimension of the chocolate bar

Comment: @Aamosh Dahal added a code.. you can work on top of that.. hope it helps

Comment: @Jobin I added the full code for you please help me through this. This is the only thing that's blocking me.

Comment: hi.. will check it

Comment: @Jobin Hi!! can you still help me on this matter?

Comment: have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need a loop like this..

```
    Integer[] numbers = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10};

    boolean machFound = false;

    int row = 2;
    int column = 4;
    int x = 0;

    while (!machFound && x < numbers.length) {

        if (numbers[x] % row == 0 || numbers[x] % column == 0) {

            // TODO:Do the other calculation here

            System.out.println("there is match found at index " + x);
            machFound = true;
        }

        x += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but i could not get what i wanted from your code. Could you possibly just add in my code? I really need to learn this